# How to create a class that implements java.util.collections

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to create a class  say `MyStack` that would implement a java.util.collections class. `MyStack` will override some methods of the collections class like add(similar to push), remove(similar to pop) etc.. I intend to model the class on the same lines as a `Set` or  other interfaces of the collection class except that `MyStack` would not be an interface or abstract class and that we can create objects of type `MyStack`.

I have problems with the syntax as I am not sure if I am proceeding in the right direction.All I have so far is something like this - NOTE - None of the methods have been defined so far - I am trying to get teh skeleton right before proceeding to define the methods.

```
import java.util.*;


public class MyStak implements java.util.Collection<E>{

    public boolean add(E o){

               return false;        
        }

       public boolean addAll(Collection c){
        return false; 

        }

       public void clear() {

       }

        public boolean contains(Object o){
          return false;

        }

        public boolean containsAll(Collection o){
          return false;

        }

        public boolean equals(Object c){
          return false; 
        }

        public int hashcode(){
          return 0; 
        }

        public boolean isEmpty(){
          return false; 
        }

        public Iterator iterator(){
          return null;

        }

        public boolean remove(Object o){
          return false; 
        }

        public boolean removeAll(Collection o){
          return false; 
        }

        public boolean retainAll(Collection o){
          return false; 
        }

        public int size(){
          return 1; 
        }

         public Object[] toArray(){
           return null;

         }

         public Object[] toArray(Object[] a){
           return null; 
         }

    }
```

I have a couple of compile time errors like -

```
    +public class MyStak implements java.util.Collection<E>{
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type MyStak must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Collection<E>.add(E)
    - E cannot be resolved to a type

    +public boolean add(E o){
Multiple markers at this line
    - E cannot be resolved to a type
    - implements 
     java.util.Collection<E>.add
```

Any code modifications, examples , corrections to my code , links to tutorials etc will we highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what data type is your custom stack going to store, or is it going to be generic? The issue here is that you need to define a type for E or just go MyStak<E> :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure to throw on a `<E>` specification on your class as well:

```
public class MyStak<E> implements java.util.Collection<E>
                   ^^^
```

If you want to make life easier on yourself try sub-classing [`AbstractCollection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) instead of implementing `Collection` directly. It provides reasonable default implementations for most of the methods to minimize the amount of code you need to write.

> #### <sub>java.util</sub>
>
> #### [Class `AbstractCollection<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html)
>
> This class provides a skeletal implementation of the `Collection` interface, to minimize the effort required to implement this interface.
>
> To implement an unmodifiable collection, the programmer needs only to extend this class and provide implementations for the `iterator` and `size` methods. (The iterator returned by the `iterator` method must implement `hasNext` and `next`.)
>
> To implement a modifiable collection, the programmer must additionally override this class's `add` method (which otherwise throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`), and the iterator returned by the `iterator` method must additionally implement its `remove` method.
>
> The programmer should generally provide a `void` (no argument) and `Collection` constructor, as per the recommendation in the `Collection` interface specification.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any article link to describe your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You were VERY close!

You just need to define E in your subclass as well:

```
public class MyStak<E> implements java.util.Collection<E>
```

The idea is that you could have a subclass with, say, `<E, F, G>`, and you implement two different interfaces, one using E, one using F. That, or MyStak could be specialized and use a specific class for `Collection`, instead of a generic `E`.

Answer (score 2):

And one recommendation, if you plan to implement your own collection interface consider extending corresponding abstract class, but not implementing interface itself, cause abstract classes implement methods general to the interface.
Look at: AbstractCollection, AbstractSet, AbstractList

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
public class MyStak implements java.util.Collection<E>{
```

try:

```
public class MyStak<E> implements java.util.Collection<E>{
```

Answer (score 0):

When we implement Collection along with we must implement `Iterator<E>` also. Which is use to iterate over the item on which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is defining a stack what you really want to achieve? If so, then go ahead and define it without even implementing Collection interface - it will be OK for simple cases. Or use an existing class - java.util.Stack.