# Problems implementing java.util.Collection<E> and overriding methods

Tags: java, collections

I have a java assignment where i am supposed to construct a class that works like a Multiset. The class has to implement the interface Collections. I have tried to do this and declare all the methods that are in Collections (found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)). But when i compile this code I get the following error:

```
error: TreeMultisetNy is not abstract and does not override abstract method retainAll(Collection<?>) in Collection
```

Why is this happening?

Heres my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TreeMultisetNy<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Collection<E> {
private Map<E, Integer> data = new TreeMap<E, Integer > ();

public boolean add(E ny) { 
    return true;
}
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c){
    return false;
}
public void clear() {

}
public boolean contains(E what) {
    return false;
}
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return false;
}
public boolean equals(E what) {
    return false;
}
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return false;
}
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return null;
}
public boolean remove(E what) {
    return false;
}
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return false;
}
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return false;
}
public int size() {
    return 0;
}
public Object[] toArray() {
    return null;
}
public Object[] toArray(Object[] a){
    return null; 
}
}
```

I found this question:
[How to create a class that implements java.util.collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301163/how-to-create-a-class-that-implements-java-util-collections)
But I dont believe I am making the same mistake as that guy, or am i wrong?

Please give me some hints, i have been coding php for years but object orientation is new to me!

Comment: Try using the method signature `public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)` instead of `public boolean retainAll(Collection<E> c)`.

Comment: and `public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` . Also hava a look at AbstractCollection - extending that instead of implementing the whole interface yourself may save some work.

Comment: What they mean by 'is not abstract' is that because your class is not abstract, it has to implement all of the methods.

Comment: You may be able to reduce the amount of work by extending java.util.AbstractCollection. You still have to implement a few methods, but not as many as you are doing.

Comment: Thanks @TedHopp that saved me a couple of errors!

Comment: @flup which do you mean by "all the methods"? I have already implemented all methods of ´Collection´, do i need to implement even more?

Comment: @user2254899 The method signature is very important, if the arguments have a different type, the method does not count. Read the error message to find out which one's still missing/has incorrect type.

Answer (score 1):

The correct signatures for the "`All`" methods are as follows:

```
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c)
boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
```

You need to change your class accordingly.

Also, the signature of the one-arg version of `toArray()` is wrong. It should be

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

There are other errors the same lines. You need to carefully go through your class, making sure each method has exactly the correct signature.

See [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you, that got rid of all the errors except for the first one :)

Comment: @user2254899: Which one is the first?

Comment: "error: TreeMultisetNy is not abstract and does not override abstract method retainAll(Collection<?>) in Collection"

Comment: @user2254899: Well, does it override `retainAll(Collection<?>)`, *with this exact signature*?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not following you. I have now updated the question with my current code and the remaining error